# How to communicate with Win CE device connected by usb

Tags: c#, windows-ce, communication

Greetings.

I'm trying to communicate between desktop PC and Windows CE 5.0 device connected by usb (cradle).

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, because I can't find how to establish connection between them. What namespace to look? I just want simple communication: connect, exchange some data, disconnect. Sockets are more then enough, but what address should I access? The one assigned by usb connection on handheld is not accessible on desktop machine.

Communication should be initiated from desktop PC.
My handheld is running Windows CE 5.0 with .NET Compact Framework 2.0

Please point me to the right direction :)

Comment: Having same issue with CE 7.0 Symbol device. I am trying to connect by the server client sample application given in Windows Mobile 6.5.3 SDK. Anyone have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ActiveSync connection with the device. If you do, use [OpenNETCF desktop communication](http://rapi.codeplex.com/). It is exatly what you are looking for.

Comment: I found that library, but can only use it to create and read files on CE device. It is hardly "communication" but luckily requirements of project changed and it is sufficient :)
I'm still looking for a way to "on-line" talk with connected device.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it appears that mobile device won't popup in FileOpenDialog.

Use Rapi? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/4826aa50-f206-499e-b115-584c3f058f8a

[or check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920177.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create and use server application for desktop, do data communication trough socket. You can transfer whatever you want.